# Problema -> Carrinho de compras incrementa produtos ao dar refresh na página - PHP

Tags: php, html

Da série "Estou tentando fazer um sistema de carrinho de compras completo" kk, eu possuo mais um problema. Só pra enfatizar que eu sou iniciante em programação e estou estudando o máximo de funcionalidades e uma delas é referente a carrinho de compras por isso costumo fazer bastantes perguntas sobre o mesmo.

Vou explicar meu problema mas antes irei dizer como está o sistema:

## EXPLICAÇÃO BREVE:

Eu tenho o carrinho de compras pegando os produtos do banco de dados e inserindo no front da aplicação. Então, há também a funcionalidade adicionar quantidade de um mesmo produto, isso está ok. É aquilo básico, se já existe uma array com um item, ele incrementa mais 1 e por aí vai. Pra remover está tudo certo. Agora vem a bomba ^^

## PROBLEMA:

O meu problema está em duas coisas:
1º Quando eu adiciono um produto ou removo, ele dá um refresh na página e a minha ideia é que ele não faça esse refresh e sim faça em Run Time;

2º Considere o exemplo:
Microfone
Preço: 30,00
Qtde: 1;

Webcam
Preço: 22,00
Qtde: 3; { <====== Esse foi o último produto adicionado, 3 quantidade do segundo produto.}

O problema é que se eu dou um Atualizar, ele envia novamente a requisição de adicionar item e incrementa +1 no último produto adicionado.

Fui claro? Eu sempre acho que explico do meu jeito e é todo bugado mas é só falarem ai que eu "traduzo" kkkk

Bom, esses são os meus problemas, e para não ficar só nas minhas palavras haha, eu vou add o código do meu carrinho, blz? Lembrando que eu sei que possivelmente o erro está em relação à SESSION's mas eu ainda não entendo toda a aplicação e forma de aplicar que ela possui entao conto muito com a ajuda de vocês.
Segue código:

```
<?php
/* Inicializa uma sessão */
//session_start();

/* Verifica se já existe uma sessão ativa */
if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'])){
    $_SESSION['itens'] = array();
}

/* Inicializa uma sessão */
if(isset($_GET['add']) && $_GET['add'] == 'carrinho'){
    $idProduto = $_GET['id'];
    if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto])){
        $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] = 1;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] += 1;
    }
}

/* Mostrar carrinho de compras */
echo "<div>";
if(count($_SESSION['itens']) == 0){ /* Se a sessão itens estiver vazia, retorna uma mensagem */
    echo "<div style='display : relative; float : right;'>Carrinho Vazio<br/><a href='index.php'>Adicionar Itens</a>";
}else{
    /* Cria conexão e retorna os na session itens os produtos e suas info como um array. */
    $conection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lanchenet', 'admin', 'nuttertools'); 
    foreach($_SESSION['itens'] as $idProduto => $qtde){
        $query = $conection->prepare("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE id=?");
        $query->bindParam(1, $idProduto);
        $query->execute();
        $produtos = $query->fetchAll();
        $total = $qtde * $produtos[0]["valor"];
        echo
            $produtos[0]["nome"].'<br/>
            Preço: '.number_format($produtos[0]["valor"], 2, ",", ".").'<br/>
            Quantidade: '.$qtde.'<br/>
            Total: '.number_format($total, 2, ",", ".").'
            <a href="sistema.php?p=cardapio&remover=carrinho&id='.$idProduto.'">Remover</a>
            ';
        ;
    }
 echo "</div>";
 echo "</div>";
}

if(isset($_GET['remover']) && $_GET['remover'] == 'carrinho'){
    $idProduto = $_GET['id'];
    $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] -= 1;
    if ($_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto == 0]){
        unset($_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto]);
    }
    echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0; URL=sistema.php?p=cardapio"/>'; 
}

echo "</div>";
```

?>

Belê? Se precisar de alguma outra parte de código é só falar que eu add.
Mas é isso, eu quero muito entender essa parada rsrsrs então, qualquer comentário que contribua para um melhor entendimento dessa questão, vai me ajudar muito.. Grato a todos NAÇÃO! ^^

Comment: Olá Lougans, o add está duplicando porque somente no remover que você redireciona o usuário para uma url sem as variáveis _GET. Minha sugestão: coloque tudo no inicio do PHP, add e remover. Em ambos casos você manipula a variável de _SESSION e depois redireciona o usuário. Mas tenta usar o header('Location:') ao invés de tag html <meta>

Comment: Opa, mano.. Seu comentário foi bem útil, irei seguir sua dica! vlwww